# Pandas select value in one dataframe, based on value in other df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

df1:

```
         GAME  PLAY  BET
0  (SWE, FIN)  DRAW   10
1  (DEN, GER)   WIN   20
2  (RUS, CZE)  LOSS   30
```

df2:

```
     GAME   WIN  DRAW   LOSS
0  (SWE, FIN)  1.50   2.0   3.25
1  (DEN, GER)  2.00   2.5   2.10
2  (RUS, CZE)  1.05   2.1  10.00
```

I'd like to create a column "PAYOFF" in df1, for each game. Payoff is computed by fetching the actual odds (WIN/DRAW/LOSS) from df2, by multiplying that value with the "BET" from df1. For instance, for row 1, (SWE,FIN), the PLAY was a DRAW, and I need to use that value to fetch from the DRAW col in df2.
I can manage that by joining the 2 df's, and then some ugly del/rename of columns in a number of steps, but surely I'm missing some more elegant way to do that ?  TIA, --Tommy

Comment: Can you give us an example of what output you expect with the data you have supplied?

Comment: For each of the rows in df1, I'd like to compute BET multiplied by the corresponding odds  from df2, given there in three separate columns. So for instance, for df1 row 0, where the play was DRAW, I'd fetch from df2, row0, the value in the  DRAW column, which is 2.0, and then multiply that with the BET value, 10, of row 0 df1. And doing so for all the rows in df1. NOTE that there might be more rows in df1 than in df2, for instance, there might be several different bets on the SWE-FIN game...

Comment: @Pryderide You're welcome. Just note you need 4 spaces before each row of a table.

Answer (score 2):

I think need `lookup`

```
df1['New']=df2.set_index('GAME').lookup(df1.GAME,df1.PLAY)
df1
Out[26]: 
        GAME  PLAY  BET   New
0  (SWE,FIN)  DRAW   10   2.0
1  (DEN,GER)   WIN   20   2.0
2  (RUS,CZE)  LOSS   30  10.0
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Wasn't aware of `lookup`.

Comment: @Wen Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: @Pryderide yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

I like Wen's solution better, but you can use

```
merged = pd.merge(
    pd.concat([df1, pd.get_dummies(df1.PLAY)], axis=1),
    df2,
    on='GAME')
>>> merged.BET * (merged.DRAW_x * merged.DRAW_y + merged.WIN_x * merged.WIN_y + merged.LOSS_x * merged.LOSS_y)
0     20.0
1     40.0
2    300.0
dtype: float64
```